# How to write Airflow DAG using KubernetesPodOperator to submit Spark Jobs

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow

I have stumbled upon so many answers around how to write an Airflow DAG using KubernetesPodOperator to submit Spark Jobs. After struggling for days and finding not a proper syntax, somehow I get it working. Posting an answer here, so that others don't struggle much :)

Answer (score 0):

Below Airflow DAG uses KubernetesPodOperator to submit a Spark Job wherein it reads the PySpark script from Ceph. Same syntax should work if your PySpark script is in AWS S3. For AWS S3 you don't need to pass `fs.s3a.endpoint`, `fs.s3a.connection.*`, `f3.s3a.path.*`

```py
# Airflow DEMO DAG

from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator

args = {
    "owner": "prateek.dubey",
    "email": ["<your_email_id>"],
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2019,1,1),
    "catchup": False, 
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='kubernetes_sample_dag', default_args=args, schedule_interval=None)

ceph_data_read = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='airflow',
        image='spark-executor-3.0.1',
        image_pull_policy='Always',
        image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference('gcr')],
        service_account_name='spark',
        name='prateek-ceph-data-read',
        task_id='ceph_data_read',
        in_cluster=True,
        get_logs=True,
        arguments=[
                '/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit',
                '--master', 'k8s://https://<api_server_host>:6443',
                '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                '--name', 'prateek-ceph-data-read',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=prateek-ceph-data-read',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix=prateek-ceph-data-read',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.namespace=airflow',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark-executor-3.0.1',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=gcr',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.executor.serviceAccountName=spark',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt',
                '--conf', 'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token',
                '--conf', 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider',
                '--conf', 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=http://<ceph_endpoint_url>:8080',
                '--conf', 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled=false',
                '--conf', 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true',
                '--conf', 'spark.executor.instances=2',
                '--conf', 'spark.executor.cores=6',
                '--conf', 'spark.executor.memory=55g',
                's3a://<ceph_bucket>/Ceph_PySpark_Read_Data.py'
            ],
        dag=dag
    )

ceph_data_read
```

Comment: `from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator` is deprecated. You should use `from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator`